# html link error in xml

Tags: youtube, xml, parsing

I am trying this in xml:

```
<a class='mybtn' href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=VIDEOID'><i class='myclass'/></a>
```

but I get this error:

*Error parsing XML, column 77: The reference to entity "loop" must end with the ';' delimiter.*

Column 77 is at the end of the word loop.

Where is the error as when I copy it to my browser it works.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Post at least the enclosing elements please.

Comment: I just did it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ampersand (`&`) in an XML text node or attribute must always be written as `&amp;`.

Alternatively, many sites accept ";" to separate URL query parameters, as an alternative to `&`.

Comment: Thanks! I used ";" instead of "&" and worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to process HTML as XML which is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572928/parsing-an-html-document-using-an-xml-parser). Additionally, ampersands must be [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml/12524924) in XML. I would recommend you explore that first link for a suitable alternative parser.